# What alternatives to the Venn diagram are there to show alignment of 2 things?

Tags: info-visualisation

The Venn diagram is probably the most common way to show alignment, but we're looking for something more fresh. However, we don't want to require our users to understand advanced math in order to read our graph.

Answer (score 1):

The Venn Diagram is one of the simplest and easiest to understand ways to show overlapping data. You can still use a Venn Diagram but present it in a fresh way that's more than just two intersecting circles. Like you can use different shapes like diamonds or triangles. I've seen some that showed intersecting similar objects such as coffee cups or faces or light bulbs.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Matthew's answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/124647/64458). There are many shapes you can use to show alignment of two things. I use light bulb shapes to show the interactions of things. If you want you can create cute faces on the bulbs; this will help to catch the interest of people.